# I can't use a npm package in my Node.js project

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I want to use `snap-tweet` in my Node.js app. [Here is the source code](https://github.com/privatenumber/snap-tweet)

I have installed the package using this command: `npm i -g snap-tweet`.

And my code looks like this:

```js
const TweetCamera = require('snap-tweet')

TweetCamera.snapTweet('1420000000000000000');
```

But I am getting this error: `TypeError: TweetCamera.snapTweet` is not a function.

So I debugged the `TweetCamera` object and found that it returned `{ default: [Getter] }`. When I log `TweetCamera.default`, I get `[class yn]`.

When I write `const tweetCamera = new TweetCamera()`, I get this error: `TypeError: TweetCamera is not a constructor`.

So I don't really know what is happening right here. Even after reading the source code, I can't find where I'm messing up. I'm new to Node.js app development, so your help would be awesome.

Comment: have you read the docs on how to use

Comment: Bruh have you seen the github repo ? The only thing explained is how to use it via a command line. You are not helping me right now or I missed something

Comment: what if thats the way it is supposed to be used

Comment: What if I'm importing it incorrectly and didn't understand that it wasn't coded for the way I want to use it because I'm not an expert?

Comment: you could try to run the cli commands in your js script if that gets the job done

Comment: what i meant was what if it is written as a cli tool not something you can import and use

Comment: Yes, well I recoded it into js, and put in my `packages.json` file that my project was of type `module`.